# Expressing the gravitational potential energy of a box as a function of the angle between the bottom of the box and the floor

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, statics

lets say there is a box with a mass of 80 kg it is 0.6 m wide, 0.6 m deep, and 1.2 m high.

[image]

lest call the gravitational potential energy U then:

$$ U = -\int_{r1}^{r2}F \cdot dr $$

lets call the force that tilted the box F_t then I think ft should be:

$$F_t = ma + mgsin\theta$$

lets say F_t exerts a torque then:

$$I\frac{a}{R} = F_t $$

the gravitational potential energy a box as a function of the angle between the bottom of the box and the floor should be "(wrong)":

$$U = -Ft ( 0.6sin\theta - 0.6cos\theta)$$

my question is how to express the gravitational potential energy of the box as a function of the angle between the bottom of the box and the floor

Comment: What is $r_1$? What is $r_2$? What is $a$? What is $R$? In the case where $a=0,$ why is $F_t$ vanishingly small when $\theta$ is a vanishingly small positive angle (the lower left corner of the box has barely been lifted from the floor), while $F_t$ is at its maximum value when the box has completely fallen over on the side of length $1.2$ (when $\theta$ is $90$ degrees)? Try working through the problem much more carefully after defining exactly what you want each of your symbols to mean, and edit the question to show what you did.

Comment: What actually is the question? Is it to show why the final formula is wrong? Is it to show why the final formula is correct? Is it to find the gravitational potential energy of the box? Since the workings in the question at this moment make no sense, we can't really say what's wrong or right about the last formula; whereas to actually find the formula would just be a "do my homework" exercise since you haven't actually contributed anything yet.

Comment: the main goal is to express the gravitational potential energy a box as a function of the angle between the bottom of the box and the floor. I am having trouble setting up the integral at least I try.

Comment: Why do you need to use an integral at all? Gravitational potential energy is easily computed just by studying the configuration of the masses, without needing to consider how they got into that configuration.

Comment: @DavidK can you elaborate more on that one?

Comment: the book answer is  U = 5.3 X 10^2 J X {sin(theta + tan^-1 2) +
[constant]}; so there must be some integration involved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145271/discussion-between-david-k-and-pulsar-plasma).